# How do I get my server HSM working while connected via RDP? (Win 2019)

Tags: windows-server-2019, smartcard

The error I get from pkcs11-tool.exe is "No slots."

My server has a hardware security module (Nitrokey HSM 2) that becomes inaccessible once I connect to my server via Windows Remote Desktop.

Note: this is NOT for logging in with smart cards. I use my HSM to decrypt data with its private key.

I use this HSM with the pkcs11-tool.exe recommended by Nitrokey.

It does not matter whether or not I uncheck the box "Smart Cards or Windows Hello for Business". A workaround is to use a different program (AnyDesk) to connect to the server, but that is not a solution because I don't want to rely on a 3rd party remote access app.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to categorize this subject, so I tried my luck in the Security Stack Exchange and got my answer there. This is my post:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/256336/how-do-i-get-my-server-hsm-working-while-connected-via-rdp-win-2019/256391#256391